# android map markers don't show

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to implement a simple application and using the fragments I'm trying to mark spots in a map.

My fragment has the following code:

```
package pt.com.hugo_dias.hstapplication.customer.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.List;

import pt.com.hugo_dias.HSTApplication;
import pt.com.hugo_dias.hstapplication.R;
import pt.com.hugo_dias.hstapplication.customer.database.Customer;
import pt.com.hugo_dias.hstapplication.customer.database.CustomerDatabaseHelper;
import pt.com.hugo_dias.hstapplication.customer.exceptions.CustomerException;

public class GoogleMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the item ID that this fragment
     * represents.
     */
    private CustomerDatabaseHelper customerHelper;
    private GoogleMap mMap;


    public GoogleMapFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        View rootView = null;
        long id = getActivity().getIntent().getLongExtra("ID", 0);
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        getMapAsync(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    public CustomerDatabaseHelper getCustomerHelper() {
        if (customerHelper == null) {
            customerHelper = new CustomerDatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        }
        return customerHelper;
    }

    public void setCustomerHelper(CustomerDatabaseHelper customerHelper) {
        this.customerHelper = customerHelper;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mMap = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        long id = getActivity().getIntent().getLongExtra("ID", 0);
        if (id == 0) {
            Log.i(HSTApplication.TAG, "Customer id cannot be 0 ");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.customerdoesntexists,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        Customer customer;
        try {
            customer = getCustomerHelper().getCustomer(id);
        } catch (CustomerException e) {
            Log.i(HSTApplication.TAG, "Customer does not exists - " + id);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.customerdoesntexists,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        double latitude = customer.getLatitude();
        double longitude = customer.getLongitude();

        LatLng position = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                position).title(customer.getName()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 10));
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        try {
            List<Customer> dependencies = getCustomerHelper().getDependencies(id);
            for(Customer dependency : dependencies){
                position = new LatLng(dependency.getLatitude(), dependency.getLongitude());
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                        position).title(dependency.getName()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
            }
        } catch (CustomerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the markers are not shown but I see the method to be called during debug.

Comment: First make sure the "addMarker" code is called. Also, Make sure you have correct long and lat values

Comment: They are correct as seen in debug.

Comment: So you added the lat/lng to google map ( on browser) and made sure you can see them, correct? Because onceI  thought I was using the correct values and they were outside my region.  Another suggestion is to move the code with the "addMarker" to after "setMapType"

Comment: Just appear the earth map. The mapType was to try if it changed anything, but didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your code gives an impression that you are fetching markers from a Database as you are creating an object of `CustomerDatabaseHelper`. But eventually the code for that file is missing. If you just want to display marker with a long click on your Maps fragment without storing them into database and fetching them out making things simple, Just copy and paste this code in your MainActivity.java:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
//import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
//import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
 implements OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener{

 final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
 private GoogleMap myMap;

 Location myLocation;
 TextView tvLocInfo;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  tvLocInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locinfo);

  FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

MapFragment myMapFragment 
   = (MapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
  myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();

  myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

  myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
  //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
  //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
  //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

  myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
  myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);

 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
     case R.id.menu_legalnotices:
      String LicenseInfo = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(
        getApplicationContext());
      AlertDialog.Builder LicenseDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
      LicenseDialog.setTitle("Legal Notices");
      LicenseDialog.setMessage(LicenseInfo);
      LicenseDialog.show();
         return true;
     }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onResume();

  int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

  if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
     "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
   GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);
  }

 }

 @Override
 public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
  tvLocInfo.setText(point.toString());
  myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
 }

 @Override
 public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
  tvLocInfo.setText("New marker added@" + point.toString());
  myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(point.toString()));
 }

}
```

Hope that Helps!!